# Determine if this matrix can be written as a linear combination of these matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can this matrix be written as a linear combination of these matrices below?
\begin{bmatrix}
-12\\
12\\
-18\\
-8\\
\end{bmatrix}

---

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-3\\
3\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-2\\
4\\
5\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
-5\\
10\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I approach this kind of problem? Do I need to start with an augmented matrix form and turn it into a reduced row-echelon form? I'm lost as my textbook doesn't really explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to determine whether the first matrix can be represented as a linear combination of the others.

The simplest way could be to solve for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following is true:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
-12\\
12\\
-18\\
-8
\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-3\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}+b
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
-2\\
4\\
5
\end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
-5\\
10\\
6
\end{bmatrix}$

This can be turned into a system of equations shown below:

$$3a+3b+6c=-12$$
$$-3a-2b-5c=12$$
$$3a+4b+10c=-18$$
$$3a+5b+6c=-8$$

I will leave it up to you to solve for such $a,b,c$.

Another method you can use to approach this problem is to check for [linear dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). You can do this as you said by row-reducing the 4x4 matrix formed by the 4 column vectors.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
-12&3&3&6\\
12&-3&-2&-5\\
-18&3&4&10\\
-8&3&5&6
\end{bmatrix}$
If the row reduction leads you to the identity matrix, then you have a matrix of full rank (none of the column vectors are linearly dependent). However, if you have arrive at a matrix which only has 3 or fewer leading 1s, then you have a matrix whose column vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Note: I found Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler a great book to conceptually understand the material: http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387982582

Comment: can you specify which chapter if possible?

Comment: yes I know to solve for a, b, c but what is the algorithm or strategy to do that? @sisyphus58

Comment: Chapter 2 deals with linear independence which would be helpful in this case.

Comment: I updated my solution and included a system of equation to solve for a,b, and c.
My university used Linear Algebra and Differential Equations by Stephen A. Goode for the LADE course. It's a good book to self-teach the material (if need be) and it has numerous exercises and solved examples. I would recommend it.

Comment: The book of Axler is indeed excellent.